# pencilkitのインクの解像度が悪い

Tags: swift

pencilkitを使ってノート機能を実装しようとしています。
scrollViewを使って、画面の拡大をできるようにしたのですが、拡大後のインクの解像度が悪いです。
拡大してもインクがはっきり映るように工夫はできるでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 試したこと

canvasViewの大きさを2倍にして、scrollViewに0.5倍の大きさで表示する→変わらず。サイズを大きくしすぎるとアプリがクラッシュしました。

#### 実際のコード

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
import PencilKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UIScrollViewDelegate{
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let canvas = PKCanvasView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setCanvasView()
        setScrollView()
    }
    
    func setCanvasView(){
        canvas.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .red, width: 3)
        canvas.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        canvas.layer.borderWidth = 1
        canvas.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    //ScrollView設定
    func setScrollView(){
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 104, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        
        scrollView.addSubview(canvas)
        scrollView.contentSize = canvas.frame.size
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
    
    // pdfViewのサイズが ScrollView の表示範囲より小さい場合に画面中央に配置されるように contentInset を設定する
    func updateContentInset() {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: max((scrollView.frame.height - canvas.frame.height) / 2, 0),
            left: max((scrollView.frame.width - canvas.frame.width) / 2, 0),
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0
        )
    }
    
    //ピンチしたときに呼ばれ、拡大後のpdfViewを返す
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return canvas
    }    
}
```